# Execute procedures in parallel within a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to run procedures within a package in parallel?
I need all the procedures to run but they dont have to run sequentially.
All inserting to one table but each procedure using a different source.
Can I execute all at the one time so that total run time equals that of the longest running procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_BODY AS

PROCEDURE PRC_ONE;
PROCEDURE PRC_TWO;
PROCEDURE PRC_THREE;

PROCEDURE PRC_RUN-INSERTS AS 
BEGIN


PRC_ONE;
PRC_TWO;
PRC_THREE;

END;

PROCEDURE PRC_ONE AS 
 INSERT INTO TBL_TARGET FROM TBL_SOURCE_ONE
END

PROCEDURE PRC_TWO AS 
 INSERT INTO TBL_TARGET FROM TBL_SOURCE_TWO
END

PROCEDURE PRC_THREE AS 
 INSERT INTO TBL_TARGET FROM TBL_SOURCE_THREE
END

END
```

Comment: Look into setting up a [dbms_scheduler job chain](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10021) , or use [dbms_parallel_execute](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_parallel_ex.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with executing DBMS parallel execute.

**DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE**

For more details kindly go through the below reference link

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2